# Is there any way to search in the properties of google drive files?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to search files like this but I am getting exception.

```
query = "mimeType ='application/pdf' and properties has { key="+ "'" + agency + "'" +"and value contains"+ "'" + someValue + "'" + " and visibility='PUBLIC'} ";
request = service.files().list().setQ(query);
```

Do we need to search by exact value?

```
query = "mimeType ='application/pdf' and properties has { key="+ "'" + agency + "'" +"and value = "+ "'" + someValue + "'" + " and visibility='PUBLIC'} ";
request = service.files().list().setQ(query);
```

The second one is working, but is there any feature to support wildcard characters?

Comment: What exact exception do you get after running your first query? I'm not familiar with the google drive SDK but I suppose it supports regex, doesn't it?

Comment: Alex why would you suppose an api you dont know would support regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for custom properties you have to seach with exact values

```
properties has { key='additionalID' and value='8e8aceg2af2ge72e78' and visibility='PRIVATE' }
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters#properties

Comment: thanks,but search would be handy if this feature(contains) is also allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its in official docs (thou last year they werent searchable).
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters#properties to search by exact value.